# Android Kotlin - Enum Class as parameter of a function

Tags: android, function, kotlin, parameters, enums

I have several ENUMs in the following format:

```
enum class MyEnum1(val id: Int, val titleId: Int) {
    A1(0, R.string.a1),
    B1(1, R.string.b1),
    ...
}

enum class MyEnum2(val id: Int, val titleId: Int) {
    A2(0, R.string.a2),
    B2(1, R.string.b2),
    ...
}
```

I also have a Compose dialog, that lists these values, but now I have all these enums
first converted to `List<Pair<Int,Int>>` before I give it to my dialog component, as a parameter.

How would it be possible to make the Compose function have a parameter of any Enum class type?
I'd like to call my Composable like so:

```
ListDialog( ..., enum = MyEnum1::class, ...)
also
ListDialog( ..., enum = MyEnum2::class, ...)
```

then process my data:

```
for (item in enum.values()) {
        // something
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really have experience with Compose so I'm not sure how that all works, but I have experience with kotlin in general. And what you could do is have all your enums implement a common interface. Then this is possible for example:

```
fun main() {
    test(MyEnum1.values())
    test(MyEnum2.values())
}

fun test(enum: Array<out EnumsWithIdAndTitle>){
    for (item in enum) {
        println(item.titleId)
    }
}

interface EnumsWithIdAndTitle {
    val id: Int
    val titleId: Int
}

enum class MyEnum1(override val id: Int, override val titleId: Int) : EnumsWithIdAndTitle  {
    A1(0, 11),
    B1(1, 22),
}

enum class MyEnum2(override val id: Int, override val titleId: Int) : EnumsWithIdAndTitle {
    A2(0, 33),
    B2(1, 44),
}
```

then instead of my `test` function you could modify your `ListDialog` in a similar way I think